# How to download a mysql dump from Rackspace cloud

Tags: backup, rackspace-cloud

I need to get data from a MySQL dump on Rackspace Cloud. I can see the sql.gz file I need in "Backup Contents" but it is not accessible. I have tried downloading from Cloud Files, but they make no sense on a Windows machine. Any pointers?

Comment: The file I downloaded from Cloud Files was compressed. I opened it with WinRAR and there was mention of SQLLite in the machine code, but that's as fas as I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to SSH in and do mysqldump

Comment: And then use winscp to get the file down.